# Meaning of fit_params for RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I would like to use [RandomizedSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) from scikit-learn. In the constructor I can pass `param_distributions`, i.e. the distributions for the different parameters I want to optimize. But there is also the `fit_params` attribute. From the documentation I don't see what the meaning of it is. In which cases should I use `fit_params` instead of `param_distributions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is for initialization parameters, and the other is for parameters added when the actual `fit` method is called.

Most of the things you want to vary are going to be set through `param_distributions`. Things like regularization, hyperparameters, loss functions, etc... are specific to the model instantiation.

On the other side there are pieces that are passed in to the `fit` call that can sometimes be required. For instance, `LogisticRegression` supports `sample_weights` ([docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit)). If that's important to you, then you can add those in there, but again CV is usually about locking down your hyperparameters, so I'd wager that `param_distributions` is what you're looking for most of the time.